# Convergence of mean of an irreducible Markov chain / ergodic theorem

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $\{X_n\}$ be an irreducible Markov chain on a discrete state space $\mathbb{N}$, that has a  stationary distribution $\pi$.

> **Prove or disprove** : with probability $1$: 
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}(X_1+\ldots+X_n) =\sum_{x\in \mathbb{N}}x~\pi(x).$$

Note. The text I am working on kind of suggests me that this is true.
For a proof, I had in my mind to use the Ergodic Theorem $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}(f(X_1)+\ldots+f(X_n)) =\sum_{x\in \mathbb{N}}f(x)~\pi(x)$, which holds for bounded functions $f$ on $\mathbb{N}$, but in my case $f(x)=x$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{N}.$ Should I write the above mean value as a sum $\frac{1}{n}(g(X_1)+\ldots+g(X_n))$ for a suitable bounded function $g$? If yes though, I don't see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this result true on a Complete separable metric space i.e on a Polish space? What will be the changes then, Thanks so much for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is true regardless of the initial condition. Here is a proof:

#### Claim:

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an irreducible discrete time Markov chain (DTMC) on a finite or countably infinite state space $\mathcal{S}$. Suppose it has a stationary distribution $\pi(x)$ for all $x \in \mathcal{S}$. Then for any nonnegative function $h:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and any initial condition $X_1$ we have: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i) = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}} h(x)\pi(x) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)}   $$

#### Proof part 1:

Order the states $\mathcal{S}=\{s_1, s_2, s_3, ...\}$.  Let $f_i(n)$ be the relative frequency of being in state $s_i$ in the first $n$ steps.  Then for all positive integers $n, i, k$: 
$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nh(X_i) =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} h(s_i)f_n(i) \geq \sum_{i=1}^k h(s_i)f_n(i) $$
where the inequality uses the fact that $h(\cdot) \geq 0$. 
Taking a $\liminf$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and using the fact that $f_n(i) \rightarrow \pi(s_i)$ (with prob 1) gives: 
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i) \geq \sum_{i=1}^k h(s_i)\pi(s_i)$$
The above holds for all $k>0$. Taking a limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$ gives: 
 $$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i) \geq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} h(s_i)\pi(s_i)  = \sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}} h(x)\pi(x) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} \quad (1) $$

#### Proof part 2:

Fix a state $s_1 \in \mathcal{S}$.  Define: 
$$ c = \frac{E\left[\sum_{n=1}^{T_{11}-1} h(X_n) | X_1=s_1\right]}{E[T_{11}]} $$
where $E[T_{11}]$ is the mean recurrence time from state $1$ to state $1$. The value of $c$ is possibly infinity. 
By renewal theory we know that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i) = c \quad (\mbox{with prob 1}) \quad (2) $$ 
and the above holds regardless of the initial condition. 
Now imagine starting with a *probabilistic intitial condition*: 
$$ P[X_1=x] = \pi(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathcal{S} $$
So we start out in the stationary distribution. Then $P[X_n=x]=\pi(x)$ for all steps $n$ and all $x \in \mathcal{S}$.  With this initial distribution, we have $E[h(X_n)] = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} h(x)\pi(x)$ for all time steps $n>0$. So: 
$$ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i)\right] = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} h(x)\pi(x) \quad (3)$$
On the other hand, Fatou's lemma for nonnegative random processes implies: 
$$ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i)\right] \geq E\left[ \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i)\right] = c $$
Substituting equation (3) into the left-hand-side of the above inequality gives: 
$$ \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} h(x)\pi(x)  \geq c $$
Using equation (2) in the above gives: 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nh(X_i) &\leq \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} h(x)\pi(x) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} \\
&\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nh(X_i) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} 
\end{align*}
where the final inequality uses equation (1).  This proves the claim.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer! The proof that I had in my mind made use of the fact that $f$ ($h$ in your case) in a bounded function (nothing about nonnegativity is assumed). I see that you require $f$ ($h$ in your case) to be non-negative (no requirement about boundness). Is this another version of the above Ergodic theorem or just "another" Ergodic theorem?

Comment: Well, you can recover the result for bounded functions $f(x)$ from this by defining $h(x) = M + f(x)$, where $M$ is a constant that satisfies $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x \in \mathcal{S}$, and then noting that $h$ is a nonnegative function.

Comment: Or for $\pi$-integrable $f$ by considering $f^+$ and $f_-$ separately.

Comment: I see! I was not aware of this version of the theorem! Thank you very much again both for making me aware of this, and of course the detailed answer!

Comment: @John Dawkins thanks for noting!

Comment: I generalized my answer in a second answer, along the lines of the @JohnDawkins comment.

Comment: Is this result true on a Complete separable metric space i.e on a Polish space? What will be the changes then, Thanks so much for help.

Comment: @miosaki : I don't know.  Likely a generalized version of "irreducibility" like "$\psi$-irreducible" is needed. The above proof is implicitly using the fact that 
if a stationary distribution $(\pi_i)_{i\in S}$ exists 
on a **finite or countably infinite state space $S$**, 
and if the DTMC is irreducible, then $\pi_i>0$ for all
$i \in S$, we return to each state with prob 1 (regardless
of the initial condition), and the mean recurrence time to state $i$ is 
$1/\pi_i$. This means $E[T_{11}] = 1/\pi_1$ in the definition 
of $c$, so the denominator there is not infinity.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, If you come to know please let me later.  Thanks. I am in need of a similar version but DTMC in Polish space!

Comment: @miosaki : If there is a stationary solution to steady state, and if there is a state that is returned to infinitely often with finite mean recurrence times, then part 2 of the above answer can be repeated to give with prob 1: $$ \lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i)\leq \int h(X)dP $$ where $P$ is the stationary distribution. Unfortunately the countable summation in part 1 cannot be repeated if the state space is uncountably infinite. Nevertheless a variation can likely be done when the space can be chopped into countably many small pieces and $h$ is somehow measurable.

Answer (score 3):

Generalizing my first answer in a direction suggested by John Dawkin's comment, we see the ergodicity result holds whenever the sum $\sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f(x)\pi(x)$ makes sense. Specifically, 
for general functions $f:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we define $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}} f(x)\pi(x)$ by: 
$$ \sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}} f(x) \pi(x) = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f^+(x)\pi(x) - \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f^-(x)\pi(x) $$
whenever the right-hand-side does not yield $\infty + - \infty$ (we say the sum does not exist otherwise). The functions $f^+(x)$ and $f^-(x)$ are the positive and negative parts of the function $f(x)$.   The sum $\sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f(x)\pi(x)$ can be finite, $\infty$, or $-\infty$.

#### Claim:

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is an irreducible DTMC on a finite or countably infinite state space $\mathcal{S}$. Suppose there is a stationary distribution $\pi(x)$ for all $x \in \mathcal{S}$. Suppose $f(x)$ is a function such that $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{S}} f(x)\pi(x)$ exists (possibly being $\infty$ or $-\infty$). Then: 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f(X_i) = \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f(x)\pi(x) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} $$

#### Proof:

Since $f^+(x)$ and $f^-(x)$ are nonnegative funtions,  we know by the previous answer that: 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f^+(X_n) &= \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f^+(x)\pi(x) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} \\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f^-(X_n) &= \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f^-(x)\pi(x) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} 
\end{align*} 
Now we have: 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i) &=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf^+(X_i) - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf^-(X_i)\right] \\
&= \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f^+(x)\pi(x)  - \sum_{x\in\mathcal{S}} f^-(x)\pi(x) \quad \mbox{(with prob 1)} 
\end{align*}
where the final equality holds because the limit of a sum of two functions is equal to the sum of the limits, provided that the sum of limits does not yield a situation of $\infty - \infty$.  $\Box$

Comment: Is this result true on a Complete separable metric space i.e on a Polish space? What will be the changes then, Thanks so much for help